# Android: Drawable XML

Tags: android, xml, menu

This might seem a stupid question, but I am following the Android guide on Menus;

Here [is the link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html)

Do I have to create a drawable folder under res? And inside the folder I put the pictures with name of;
ic_new_game
ic_help

? Help is much appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! If you find an answer helpful, you can vote it up! If you feel that someone has adequately answered your question, click the check-mark next to the answer to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any images you have should go in res/drawable. So make the folder drawable in your res directory and put all of your images there.

Answer (score 0):

From the tutorial,

the  game_menu.xml: goes into res/menu/

The ic_new_game goes into res/drawable

Answer (score 0):

I am basically adding to blessenm's answer. Here are a few screenshots that will help you. If you are working on Eclipse, then once you create an Android project, it should automatically contain the folders depicted in the 'project hierarchy' screenshot. Also, I decided to put the images in the mdpi (medium density) folder. Depending on the densities you are trying to support, you may choose to add images to the ldpi and hdpi folders respectively. Hope this helps!

[image: strings.xml]

[image: project hierarchy]